# Multiple criteria to display specific text

Tags: excel-formula

Formula help required to display the desired result with multiple criteria in cells.

In the below table D2 cell the formula is added to to show the result eg: F2 cell. The criteria of finding the specific text in A2 cell is the blocker in the function to give the desired result

[image]

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FF",A2)),B2=1,C2="MC"),"Fotp"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2D",A2)),B2=1,C2="MC"),"2D"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MF",A2)),B2=5,C2="MC"),"Modfix"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SE",A2)),B2=0.7,C2="SE"),"SoEv"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M Cat",A2)),B2=19,C2="MC"),"Mcat"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M cod",A2)),B2=1.25,C2="MC"),"Ing")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FF",A2)),B2=1,C2="MC"),"Fotp",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2D",A2)),B2=1,C2="MC"),"2D",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MF",A2)),B2=5,C2="MC"),"Modfix",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SE",A2)),B2=0.7,C2="SE"),"SoEv",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M Cat",A2)),B2=19,C2="MC"),"Mcat",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M cod",A2)),B2=1.25,C2="MC"),"Ing")))))))))))
```

Your original formula is not nesting the **IF**s properly.

By the way I think if you can make a look up table with all the criteria and expected result, then there is a quicker way of returning the result without the need to use nested IFs (just imagine if you have 100+ combination of criteria).